# QML use type int or real

Tags: qt, memory-management, type-conversion, int, qml

In my application, I use of lot of properties which refer to components size, images size, ... and consequently, the size is a whole number, an integer, so I use `property int mySize: 24` for example.

But in my application, for example, I do things like:

```
Rectangle{
    width: mySize * 0.75  // = 18
    height: mySize * 0.4 // = 9.6
    border.width: mySize // = 24 big border just for example :) 
}
```

In QML, all the number properties have the type `real`, so I assume QML converts my integer properties into `real` when it uses them.

My question is the following: is there any advantages to use directly the type `real` for my properties instead of `int`? Concerning the memory usage, I would say that use `int` is better than use `real`.

Comment: How important is the memory constraint given the current year we live in? Since the sizes in QML are all real, I would go with real

Comment: Even on embedded applications where memory usage can be essential? But ok, I see your point, thanks.

Comment: yes, that's why I tried to put it not so hard ;-) On the other hand, if you have an embedded system that can do QML/OpenGL, I wouldn't worry on the int/real question too much